# Registering an injected java logger that can be seen in the WAS console

Tags: java, logging, websphere

I am using WebSphere Application Server to run jakarta EE applications.

Previously, I have used the following style of log initiation:

`Logger.getLogger("uk.co.company.app.pkg.classname")`

which logs against that particular class in the trace.log/SystemOut.log file. additionally, in the WAS console, under `Troubleshooting > Logs and Trace > server > Change log level details > +Components and Groups > + * [All Components]` I can see my class listed as  `uk.co.company.app.pkg.classname.*`, because when I installed the application into WebSphere it took the registered logger and added it to its list of known loggers.

I am now moving to a different approach for log initialisation, as follows:

```java
@Inject
private Logger logger;
```

and then a producer that uses the following to get a logger that is relevant for each class:

```java
@Produces
public Logger getLogger(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
    return LoggerFactory.getLogger(injectionPoint.getMember().getDeclaringClass().getName());}
```

loggers produced this way don't register in the WAS console - or at least, mine aren't -- presumably because they're created dynamically at injection time. (note also the change from `java.util.logging` to `org.slf4j.logger` which I guess might be clouding things, but I hope not)

Is there any way to get the loggers to show up?